# Over-sensitive ears

Tags: health, ear

For some months it seems that I can hear extreme details in sounds and music. I hear each Instrument separatly, I can hear flaws in dynamic or eq treatments, I hear bad edits, reverb and delay fx. And this is a wonderful thing!

On the other hand I feel extremely under stress and my ears hurt when I get into crowds of people (e.g. Subway in rush hours, loud Moments in a cinema...).

Sometimes my right ear feels as if it blocks the loud Atmo by closing my ear (feels like water in ear) but my doctor did not find anything, my ears are perfectly fine. She told me that the effect can appear when I overload my ear.

I use a very low monitoring level with my nearfields! Also I do regular biobreaks and monitor switching to refresh my ears!

Do some of you experience something else? It feels like my ears became more sensitive!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I have experienced this (the sensativity/stress, over-anaylsis of everything I hear to the point I couldn't focus on watchin a film recreationally, etc) and it was a struggle for a year or two.  It means your ears are waking up and you are likely gaining a more conscious control/understanding lf this 'sense' (the brain has been shown to adapt over time based upon stimulus, wherein for example sound-driven people may have a larger auditory center over time than the average person).

You are certainly not alone in this overall observation.  Becoming 'conscious' to the sense can be frightening at first.

Over time, you will hopefully make peace with it and learn to develop the sense further to where you can consciously sonically analyze when you need to, but also be able to consciously 'disengage' from that frame of mind to just enjoy the spontaneous sonic beauty you can hear happening all around you with awe (a spontaneous beauty which can now be truely appreciated because of the development of consciosly being attuned to the 'sense' as opposed to taking it for granted).

Comment: Thx for the kind words! Sound is beautiful :)

Answer (score 1):

I have never experienced the symptoms that you describe, but for me I have my general mode of "hearing" and then when I need to I switch to "listening" mode.  It seems to me like you are trying to be in listening mode as your default and are then experiencing sensory overload.  As much as you need to develop you listening skills, it is vital that you control its use.  I'd suggest taking time off and going and doing something completely non-sound related (reading, exercise, etc.) so that you can get some balance back.

Answer (score 0):

happens to me all the time when i get into extended sessions of audio post. get some rest.

Answer (score 0):

Sensitive hearing has never provided me with pain/discomfort, however, I'm always careful to keep a pair of earplugs handy for louder environments. Training the ears will reveal more detail, just make sure sufficient rest is also taken.